# Given $f(x) = x^3 + x + 1$, is $\sqrt{-31}$ in $\mathbb{Q}[x]/(f)$? In the splitting field $K$ of $f$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory

Given $f(x) = x^3 + x + 1$, is $\sqrt{-31}$ in $\mathbb{Q}[x]/(f)$? In the splitting field $K$ of $f$?

This is a problem from Artin's Algebra I'm looking at for test prep.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Hint**:  $-31$ is the discriminant of the polynomial.  So if $a_1, a_2, a_3$ are the roots of $f$, then:

$$\Delta = -31 = (a_1 - a_2)^2(a_1-a_3)^2(a_2-a_3)^2$$

So is $\sqrt{-31} \in K$?

Next, note that $\mathbb{Q}[x]/(f) \cong \mathbb{Q}[\alpha]$ where $\alpha$ is a root of $f$.  Well, $[\mathbb{Q}[\alpha]:\mathbb{Q}] = 3$ and $[\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{-31}]: \mathbb{Q}] = 2$.

If $\sqrt{-31} \in \mathbb{Q}[\alpha]$, then we have $\mathbb{Q} \subset \mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{-31}] \subset \mathbb{Q}[\alpha]$.  Can you find a contradiction here?

Comment: $-31$ is indeed the discriminant of $f$, but it is clearly not the result of the multiplication you wrote, as the latter involves only positive terms.

Comment: That is how Artin *defines* the discriminant.  Note that two of the roots are complex.

Comment: Snap, didn't realize the $a_i$'s were the roots of $f$. Sorry!

Comment: No problem!  It's that time of night :P

Comment: @KajHansen So $\sqrt{-31} \in K$ because all the roots of $f$ are, but I'm not seeing the contradiction. Why can't $\mathbb{Q}[\alpha] \approx K$?

Comment: @KajHansen Actually the contradiction is that $[K:\mathbb{Q}] = 3$ but $[\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{-31}:\mathbb{Q}] = 2 \nmid 3$, right?

Comment: Yep, that's exactly it.